# QT Program segfaults when trying to instantiate QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qml, qwidget

I have a simple QT project that looks like the following:

```
#include <QtWidgets/qwidget.h>

TempClass::TempClass() {
    QWidget* tempWidget = new QWidget();
}
```

Everything compiles fine, but when I try to run the program it segfaults on the line that instantiates a new QWidget. FYI I am using QT 5.7.1.

Comment: That's probably not enough information. Are you creating a `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication`?

Comment: It's a QGuiApplication:

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv); (in main.cpp)

Comment: If this is on Windows make sure that whatever compiler you are using is the same (including version if you are using Visual Studio) as Qt was built with. Also make sure that the correct .dlls are in your path. If the wrong version of Qt binaries are used a crash is expected.

Comment: The binaries must be correct because I'm easily able to compile and run built-in QT examples that utilize QWidget (i.e. Welcome -> Examples -> Scribble). However, when I cut and paste identical code from one of those examples into my project, it always segfaults on the QWidget instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I was instantiating my application as a QGuiApplication vs. a QApplication. Once I changed the code to the following, my QWidget instantiates properly:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```